# ComboBox - Align and pad text for selected item, and create mouse rollover for combobox items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm currently designing a minor application for a program our site will be using and have come across problem after problem regarding combo boxes. I've finally got it to the basic stage that it needs to be at, but I'm facing issues with styling the text so that it is centrally aligned and padded by 5 pixels for the current selected item. I've tried adding Setters to where I think is correct, I've tried adding `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` to the main XAML file but nothing shifts it.

[image]

What I would also like to do is when the options are rolled over, they have a different background colour. I've tried adding a MouseOver Visual State to ComboBoxItem but to no avail. Apologies in advance for the lengthy code (and probably messy). It's been a learn on the go job with most of it coming from MSDN and then being edited as needed. Many thanks.

CODE: http://pastebin.com/gQpp2W3U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the parameters `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` not transferred to the ControlTemplate in `ContentPresenter` properly:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                  ...
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
</ContentPresenter>
```

In this case, the parameters are "sewn", should be as follows:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                  ...
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
</ContentPresenter>
```

For dynamic background element necessary add a triggers in `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` section, previously adding the name for the common Grid of `ComboBox`:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="BATTLEFIELD4">
        <Setter TargetName="MainGrid" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="CALLOFDUTY4">
        <Setter TargetName="MainGrid" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="CS">
        <Setter TargetName="MainGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Example of using:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="TestArray" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <sys:String>BATTLEFIELD4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>CALLOFDUTY4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>CS</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
              Foreground="White"
              Background="Blue"
              Height="60"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource TestArray}" />           
</Grid>
```

Also trivia added some details, the full version of the project can be downloaded [`here`](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!125&authkey=!AN7fqgAM3CZiXcI&ithint=file,.zip).

**`Output`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, items are now displaying vertically central!